# Low-quality duplicates of answers

Tags: discussion, flags, down-votes, low-quality-posts, duplicate-answers

It would be pretty ironic to answer a duplicate question about duplicate answers, but: There are some meta questions about duplicate answers, but they sort of assume that the answers are of similar quality or at least both a bit good.

But what if they aren't? Look for example at [gaming question 319495](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/319495). There is an already accepted answer will all the information that is needed and it has a good quality (as good as it gets for a bad question). Then someone recently dug up that question and put part of the information from the first answer into his own answer, added a needlessly complicated way to do the other thing that was already in the first answer and spiced it all up with bad grammar.

That answer added nothing useful to the already accepted answer. The current thing I do in that case is to say that in a comment and downvote the answer. Editing is not useful, because there already is an accepted answer with all information in it, flagging on the other hand is not really possible in a good way, because there is no "duplicate answer" flag reason. I could flag it as "very low quality", but that is intended for answers that are so bad that they can't be rescued by editing, which this could, but shouldn't.

If it gets enough downvotes, the text becomes a bit more grey, but otherwise nothing happens, it just stays there. Duplicate questions have a big banner onto them and the title gets changed, but answers just stay where they are, if they are at least understandable. So what should I do?

- Endure that they will stay there?
- Flag them as very low quality, even if the quality is ok?
- Flag as in need of moderator intervention? That should usually not be used for such common cases.

Comment: the accepted answer has lots of noise as well ....

Comment: Yes, but my question is meant in general. There are a lot of questions in the gaming reviews that are where there are mid-low quality duplicate answers.

Comment: downvoting is a good start, and a mod flag to let us know it's a duplicate helps mods see it. Seems reasonable.

Comment: So the third option?

Comment: @RoryAlsop What's a mod going to do with a flag like that?  An answer that's somewhat similar to another answer (but that's very clearly not plagiarized, and does add its own original content (even if you feel that content is not valuable)) doesn't merit any moderator action.  They're not going to have anything to do but decline the flag.

Comment: I see it as "clearly plagiarised" based on the OPs words. So I'd remove it as such.

Comment: @RoryAlsop What's your basis for that assertion?  I see no grounds for such an accusation.  The answer isn't actually re-using anything of the other answer; they both are using a similar solution, but of course it's a simple problem where that's really just "the answer" to it, so the fact that two people are both using the same framework method in their (originally constructed) solution doesn't make it plagiarism.

Comment: " put part of the information from the first answer into his own answer,"

Comment: @RoryAlsop Did you actually read the two answers?

Comment: Yes, and then read this question again as a standalone question in order to make a more useful comment for the general case.

Comment: @RoryAlsop So you think that telling someone to accuse someone else of plagiarism, when there is clearly no plagiarism going on, is helpful advice?

Comment: Nope. That's not even vaguely what I said. I answered the fairly specific "what to do with low quality duplicates of answers" with "downvote and flag em" that's all.

Comment: @RoryAlsop there is some reason for concern [as the OP seems to want to force delete answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302436/whats-the-reputation-minimum-to-see-in-need-of-moderator-intervention-questio#comment983728_302437). Your comments could be interpreted as *sure, go ahead* which might lead to the mods at gaming.se coming over here to complain because you said it was OK. Where I believe it is not OK and that is what Servy is responding to as well.

Comment: 1. I don't want to force deletion of that I just want to flag it for deletion, like questions. That other question isn't meant as "how do I get a moderator rank to delete them", but rather "how many people deal with this and how" and also I asked because it wasn't really documented before.
2. Here is another answer: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320126/171580 It isn't clearly plagiarism, because he didn't copy the text, but it is a post that: [A] Does answer the question, so it's not "not an answer", [B] does not promote a product or service, so it's not "spam" in SE's definition, ...

Comment: [C] is not rude or abusive, so that flag reason doesn't apply, [D] has a little bit of quality and could be edited to become a proper answer, so it's not to be flagged as "very low quality", but [E] editing it to make it a proper answer would still help nobody, because it was already answered with exactly the same information or even more (just not the exact words). [F] Downvoting alone seems not enough for me. I could also just downvote duplicates and spam and it would sort of work, but not well. If I recall correctly, it needs 5 downvotes to even just grey out a question and late answers ...

Comment: on gaming.SE usually don't get that much attention. So the only option left is to [G] flag it as "in need of moderator intervention", which again has the problem that there are only 7 people on that site dealing with that (as I found out by asking the other question). So should I instead pick option D, even though it doesn't really fit the description for that flag reason?

Comment: Another example: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/320186/171580
And I still don't know what to do. Simply downvoting it still keeps it there. On Gaming.SE there are sometimes good posts with a score of -2 and sometimes bad posts with a score of +2, but only very rarely any post with a score higher or lower than that. Meaning that there is a lot of noise in the votes, so that a score of -1 from me reviewing it basically means nothing. I think I'll start flagging them as "low quality" now, because they are technically not very good. I just wish I could add details to that flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone posts an answer that you think is bad, you can downvote it. That's exactly what downvotes are for.

There's no reason to flag the post.  It doesn't merit moderator action for any reason, and it doesn't meet any of the VLQ criteria for deletion.  You don't flag answers that you personally don't think are as useful as other answers as VLQ.