# What's the reputation minimum to see "in need of moderator intervention" questions/answers?

Tags: support, reputation, flags, privileges, moderation

In Stack Exchange, there are elected moderators and moderators by reputation. But the second kind is pretty relative, as there are [9 different reputation levels for "moderation" priviledges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges?tab=moderation). The flag reason only says "moderator", without any specification.

So at what point do you see the list of questions and answers that were flagged as "in need of moderator intervention"? Only as an elected moderator? At 10000 ("access to moderator tools")? Or a different limit? Or is it just the "close votes" review queue, requiring 3000 reputation?

Comment: And a tiny extra question: If it's not the review queue, is it the rightmost button here? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz3uc.png

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only diamonds (elected moderators and designated SE staff) can see the flags that get raised via the *In need of moderator* option.

Regular users can earn moderation privileges but they will never reach a level that makes them a moderator. Only by getting elected (or on small sites appointed by SE staff before a formal election is organized) a user becomes a moderator, gets their diamond, and with that gets access to the flag queue and other stuff that really should stay private and in trusted hands.

Flagging for a moderator should only be done for exceptional cases where the community can't moderate the post them selves. Editing, close and down voting are much better concepts for posts that don't warrant Not and Answer or Very Low Quality posts. Regular users can then take care of those posts by casting delete votes.

Comment: Isn't it a problem then to flag mid-low quality duplicate answers as "in need of moderator intervention", as was recommended to me on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302429 ? Gaming has a lot of mid-low quality duplicate answers, but only 7 elected moderators (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). If I now start flagging maybe 5 answers daily that way and other people do the same, wouldn't that noticeably increase the amount of work for the moderators?

Comment: Low quality answers that still answer a question shouldn't be flagged for moderators. The gaming community should down vote those and then delete those (assuming they are not salvageable with an edit). users with 20K can delete vote answers, users with 10K can delete vote questions.

Comment: The problem with that is that very late answers don't get much attention, so it gets one or two downvotes and then nothing happens with it. I continued the discussion on the other question, we better not discuss it more here.

Comment: @Fabian I recommend using meta or chat to bring older problematic posts to your community's attention.

Comment: Ok. I guess I'll make a "forgotten posts" post every month or so. Still doesn't really seem like the best way, but if it works...

Comment: @Fabian If you bump content you are likely to be suspended.  We are not a forum, don’t bump questions to the first page.

Comment: So what do I do then? With this and the discussion on the other question, we've successfully eliminated all possible ways that I could bring duplicate answers to anyone's attention.

Comment: @Fabian if you so desperate want to organize a crowd to participate in clean-up efforts, why don't you create an site chat room that you model like [Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers](https://socvr.org/faq). That room started after a meta post and then grew in number of regulars over the year being effective in clean-ups, sometimes a bit too effective and we meet resistance on Meta. But we adapt the rules then a bit so we stay within what the community feels is useful. Your room could basically be a `delv-pls` collection where users interested in that can spend their votes.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that (but not right now).